# Each time I query firestore It returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

recently when I query firestore it returns null even when there is data.
below is my code and I will share a picture of the database as well

```
   Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(widget.userId).collection('my jobs').document(widget.jobId).get().then((snapshot){
                print(snapshot.data);
});
```

widget.jobId holds the Id of the particular document I want to query, each time I run the code I get null, but the case is different when I replace the variable by manually typing the document Id, I get the result I want so I tried printing widget.jobId and I get the same result as the document Id i.e widget.jodId == document Id, so I honestly don't know why it keeps returning null.[This is a picture of the code returning null when I use the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/729kw.png)

[This is a picture of the code returning the data when I hard code the document id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1SUt.png)

thanks

Comment: did you make sure that the variable is initialized before pressing the button that call the query?

Comment: Try printing widget.jobId to check if you are really getting it. Also remove interpolation '${}' and just pass widget.jobId.

Comment: Thanks guys I figured I made a mistake in a previous implementation. I added a blank space before the widget.jobId